# PHP regular expressions issue - preg_match not returning any results

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, expression

I have a file called 1.txt and I am trying to display its part on the website.

I am trying to display a specific part between two keywords.

The file can be visible here: http://pastebin.com/GwVKhs8h

I want to display the text between these words: "(Non-Privileged).pst" and "-----Original Message-----" so it would return:

Please let me know if you still need Curve Shift.

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
$myFile = "1.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);

if (preg_match("/\(Non-Privileged\)\.pst((\n|.)*)-----Original Message-----/", $theData, $matches1))
{
    echo $matches1[1]."<br />";
}
?>
```

and I tried few things but it just doesn't work.

Comment: You should put your code in your question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just find it easier to paste the code to pastebin each time I try stuff :)

Comment: Fixed it, there were small issues in the preg_match function, the working code can be visible here in case anyone wonders: http://pastebin.com/bTqHpNZi

Comment: @dmae: You might find it easier to paste the code, but future readers of the question will probably not be able to see the code and thus this question will be useless to them.  **StackOverflow is as much about future reference for others as it is about you getting your question answered today.**

Comment: ah good to know, in this case I will paste the bit of code that was broken here I here: if (preg_match("/\(Non-Privileged\)\.pst(.*?)-----Original Message-----/s", $theData, $matches1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **explode**.

```
    $myFile = "1.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
    fclose($fh);

    $pairs = explode("(Non-Privileged).pst", $theData);
    $pairs = explode("-----Original Message-----", $pairs[1]); 
    $text  = $pairs[0]; 

    print $text;
```